# Unrecognized selector sent to instance Swift 2.1 - date picker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, unrecognized-selector

The following code causes a crash every time I save a date using the date-picker. The new date is saved, but not before XCode terminating. There's something wrong with my "DatePickerValueChanged" Please tell me why this isn't working:

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    //hide blank cells in table view
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    tableView.tableFooterView = backgroundView


    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "addNewTask")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    setupUIElements()

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerValueChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


}
```

Function:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    saveTHeCourseWork("dueDate", value: sender.date) // selected date value is saved as the value for "dueDate"
}
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Program4.DetailViewController datePickerValueChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fce737baa40
```

Comment: Does this class have a function called `datePickerValueChanged`?  You don't have it shown in your code...

Comment: You should be using the new `#selector` syntax (update to Swift 2.2!) in order to refer to obj-c selectors – that'll most probably shine a light on the problem at compile-time.

Comment: Hi, it's Swift 2.1, not objective c. Could you please show me how, I've tried everything.

Comment: @program4Life Is there a reason you can't update to Swift 2.2? Your selector string literal should be `"datePickerValueChanged:"`, as the method has an argument.

Comment: my uni only uses Swift 2.1, can't test it unless its 2.1 unfortunately

Comment: then use datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dataPickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

Comment: Sorry didn't work, I tried it just now

Comment: Is there another way. I get the feeling that it's just one little thing I'm missing. Been working on it for so long.

Comment: or just create regular function called "dubeStuff" without any parameters and in the action in viewDidLoad put `"dubeStuff"`... the function will be `saveTHeCourseWork("dueDate", value: datePicker.date)`... also dont forget to remove the reference from Story board when you delete the function datePickerValueChanged

Answer (score 1):

Your function has a parameter. This means that it requires something to be sent in the function. This is your `sender`. When you add your target, you need to ensure that your sender is being sent to the function. To do this, simply add a semi-colon to your selector.

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
```

See how I added a semi-colon after `datePickerValueChanged`. That is sending datePicker to the function. This [link](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/selectors-with-parameters-in-swift-2-2/) may help you understand this.